# Is it possible to do an call for all the data in FaunaDB?

Tags: database, next.js, relational, faunadb, fql.multiquery

I am working with the demo of fauna. I Want to have the customer in the object, but now it is @ref[I work with NextJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDsFr.png). [This is my object now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIeg6.png). How can I get my customer info straight into my object?

Answer (score 1):

Your question title asks one question, and the body asks another. Try to ask one question at a time. Also, try to use code blocks when asking about code: screenshots are not searchable, and provide an accessibility hurdle for folks with vision impairments.

For the title:

No. You can fetch up to 100 thousand documents in one query. When there are more than 100 thousand documents to retrieve, multiple queries are required.

Typically, one query would fetch documents from a single collection. If you have multiple collections, you would paginate through each collection, using as many queries as required to fetch all of the documents.

Plus, data may be attached to system schema documents, including indexes, functions, keys, tokens, credentials, access providers, collections, and databases. To capture all of these in one query, you could try starting with:

```
Map(
  Paginate(
    Union(
      AccessProviders(),
      Collections(),
      Credentials(),
      Databases(),
      Functions(),
      Indexes(),
      Keys(),
      Tokens()
    )
  ),
  Lambda("ref", Get(Var("ref")))
)
```

Each of the functions within the `Union` call return a set of their respective documents. `Union` combines them all into one set, and then `Paginate` is used to return a single page of the overall result set. Just as in your query, `Map` is used to iterate of the page of results, and the `Lambda` is used to call `Get` on each result entry in turn.

For the body:

Your query uses `Map` to run `Get` on each document matching the `all_orders` index. The result is, necessarily, an array. As such, your customer info *is* in your object, but since it appears that you have three orders, all three are in the array.

Once the result is captured in the `dbs` variable, you can (in your client code) run `forEach` or `map` on the array in `dbs.data`. As you can see from the output, each document contains its own `data` field. So, to access the first order's user-defined fields, they would be in `dbs.data[0].data`.